# How to monitor data going out of virtual box guest

Tags: proxy, virtualbox, monitoring, sniffer

I am using virtualbox to create the virtual machine. I am using Windows 10 machine as host and Windows 8 as guest.

I want to monitor the data(incoming and outgoing ) data sent by any application from guest.

I can do same thing on my host machine using proxycap and fiddler

[Proxy Cap and Fiddler](http://www.proxycap.com/bluestacks.html)

But few external application not allowing me to run fiddler and proxycap. So I thought install those application on VM and route the traffic to host.

Please let me know if it is possible? Any pointers  or suggestion to full fill this task.

Comment: You can use Wireshark for your scenario. As a best practice make the networking mode as Bridge mode and then try it. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I set the proxy on my VM to host machine

For windows Open the cmd line with admin privileges and execute the following cmd

```
netsh  winhttp set proxy hostip
```

You can use any tool to capture data in host machine like httpanalyzer.